# IBM Swift Sandbox: Running NSURLSession: Error running code: unknown error code 132

Tags: linux, swift, nsurlsession, ibm-swift-sandbox

I am trying to execute the following script:

```
import Foundation

class TestURLSession{

var session: NSURLSession!

func run(){
    session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.veenex.de/tmp/json")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    let getDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

        // HTTP Response contains an error
        if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            if httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
                print("response was not 200: \(response)")
                return
            }
        }

        // Error submitting Request
        if error != nil {
            print("error submitting request: \(error)")
            return
        }

        // print data
        if data != nil{

            do {
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray

                for entry in json {
                    print(entry)
                }

            } catch {
                print("Error printing data")
            }

        }


    });

    getDataTask.resume()
}

}

let testURLSession = TestURLSession()
testURLSession.run()
```

But I receive the error message: "Error running code: unknown error code 132.".
Executing the code in the Xcode Playground it works.

Comment: The [tag:ibm-swift-sandbox] tag is currently being discussed in [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317727/2415822) meta post.

Comment: Hey @TheSoundDefense, would love your input about the IBM-specific Swift tag in the meta post I mentioned above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A pure Swift implementation of `NSURLSession` has not been written yet.  Check out the [`NSURLSession.swift`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/NSURLSession.swift) file on Apple's GitHub repo for Foundation.

Every method is `NSUnimplemented()`, which means, well, it hasn't been implemented yet.  Until this class is finished, it will not be available for use on Linux and IBM's Swift Sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

I dug into the error and this is the message that wasn't being sent for some reason:

```
fatal error: sharedSession() is not yet implemented: file Foundation/NSURLSession.swift, line 87
0  swift            0x0000000002f4abf8 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&) + 40
1  swift            0x0000000002f493f6 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() + 54
2  swift            0x0000000002f4b726
3  libpthread.so.0  0x00007fd9dae43d10
4  libswiftCore.so  0x00007fd9d0e5eac3 _TTSf4s_s_s_n___TFs16_assertionFailedFTVs12StaticStringSSS_Su_T_ + 147
5  libFoundation.so 0x00007fd9d3a5c21f
6  libFoundation.so 0x00007fd9d3b178de
7  libFoundation.so 0x00007fd9dbce10c7
8  libFoundation.so 0x00007fd9dbce1079
9  swift            0x0000000000d0da24 llvm::MCJIT::runFunction(llvm::Function*, llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::GenericValue>) + 996
10 swift            0x0000000000d1102f llvm::ExecutionEngine::runFunctionAsMain(llvm::Function*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, char const* const*) + 1263
11 swift            0x0000000000bebdf8 swift::RunImmediately(swift::CompilerInstance&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::SILOptions const&) + 2312
12 swift            0x000000000076656e
13 swift            0x0000000000761dfe frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*) + 2590
14 swift            0x000000000075d513 main + 2835
15 libc.so.6        0x00007fd9da1e8a40 __libc_start_main + 240
16 swift            0x000000000075c8f9 _start + 41
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /usr/bin/swift -frontend -interpret /swift-execution/code-tmp.swift -target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -disable-objc-interop -module-name main -lFoundation -lETSocket 
/usr/bin/doit.sh: line 19:    10 Illegal instruction     timeout 5 swift -lFoundation -lETSocket -v /swift-execution/$fileroot
```

So yea, we have something that's not yet implemented in Swift. I will improve the error messaging in our next patch to the Sandbox.